# PocketSphinx,Python Ошибка при использовании LiveSpeech

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, pocketsphinx

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'zero_ru.cd_cont_4000'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'ru.lm'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'ru.dic')
)

print("Say something!")

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
```

При запуске вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\python\akys.py", line 14, in <module>
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'ru.dic')
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\__init__.py", line 208, in __init__
    super(LiveSpeech, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\__init__.py", line 90, in __init__
    super(Pocketsphinx, self).__init__(config)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py", line 272, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

Пытался решить разными способами нечего не выходит,словарь,языковая модель и акустическая модель в папке есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если исправить verbose=False на verbose=True можно в выводе прочитать более подробное описание проблемы. Скорее всего модель не находится в нужном каталоге.